# How to handle exception in stored procedure in mysql?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am using stored procedures for first time. I have created a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertDetails(IN userID INT, IN uname VARCHAR(40), OUT lid INT)  
BEGIN  
   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '23000'  

   INSERT INTO store_test(userid, name) 
   VALUES (userID, uname);  

   SET lid = LAST_INSERT_ID();  
END
```

I want to handle the exception of duplicate entry in the table but here when I use the third line i.e Declare a handler. The insert query stops working?

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a variable (in this example `ERROR_ER_DUP_KEY`) to determine if the error occurred.

Depending on your version of MySQL can also use [13.6.7.5. SIGNAL Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/signal.html).

```sql
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `InsertDetails`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `InsertDetails`(`puserID` INT, `uname` VARCHAR(40), OUT `lid` INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE `ERROR_ER_DUP_KEY` TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '23000' SET `ERROR_ER_DUP_KEY` := 1;
    INSERT INTO `store_test`(`userid`, `name`) VALUES (`puserID`, `uname`);
    IF (`ERROR_ER_DUP_KEY` = 0) THEN
        SET `lid` := LAST_INSERT_ID();
    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: @wcwchiquito can you please tell me where can I find resources for learning stored procedures in mysql from scratch?

Comment: @NitishHardeniya: To learn from scratch, I recommend you start with the official manual [19.1. Defining Stored Programs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-programs-defining.html), there you will find much useful information.